# AngularJS - stop angular from including element from ng-repeat from array1 if its present in array2's ng-repeat (pointer reference to the object?)

Tags: pointers, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So this is pretty self explanatory:

I have an object in array1 and I want to make a reference of object1 from array1 into array2 so array2 has a reference of that object. Then I do ng-repeat on both arrays but then both of them appear in the dom and I want only one copy to be present in the DOM.

How about if I do the same for more arrays like array3 and array4 ... doing the same thing?

Is there anything such as only keeping a reference of the object and not an actual copy, hence ng-include will not include it?

I can only think of similar thing as working with pointers in C where you literary keep a reference of the object and not a copy.

```
Array1[                    Array2[
     Object1{},                 Object5{},
     Object2{}, <--POIINTS TO-- Object2{},(JUST A REFERENCE)
     Object3{},                 Object512{},    
     Object4{},                 ...] 
     ...]
```

I currently have:
PSEUDO:
Array2.push(Array1.object2);

but that simply makes a copy of it so the ng-includes display both objects.

Any suggestions?

Comment: before thinking of an answer can I ask why you need multiple arrays? are array2,3, n all references to array 1? It looks to me more of a design question than an angular one.

Comment: even if you keep by refernce ng-repeat will traverse both arrays and wont filter duplicate values

Comment: ng-repeat actually appends to the DOM based on the array you give it. If an item is there, reference or not, it iterate over it, creating new elements. I can't even envision what you're trying to accomplish with "only one copy" but two arrays.

Comment: I am trying to draw connections between certain elements and these array. I use a drawing library where, imagine array1 and array2 are actually two objects that have an array inside of them and array1 pertains to object100.array and array2 pertains to object101.array , and I am connecting Object100 with Object2(the one that is placed in its array) and then I want to also connect object101 to object2 while keeping track of what's connected to what. The problem is that if I try and add object2 into both objects' arrays, then it's displayed twice on the DOM(two references to keep for the record).

Answer (score 0):

I *think* that I understand what you're asking, but please correct me if I don't. It appears that you have a few arrays with some data that includes duplicates and you want to display that data but filter out the duplicates.

If this is the case, I would suggest simply doing a union on all of the arrays (using something like [_.union](http://lodash.com/docs#union) and then passing the result into ng-repeat.